# Position Isotope Load More Button within Container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I am trying to build an image grid with Isotope where a "Load More"-Button is positioned within that grid, at the end after all elements.

Placing the button was not a problem, and the insert of new elements neither, however I have strictly no idea how I can ensure that button always stays after the elements. In my current code, if the "Load More" button is clicked and more elements are inserted after the button.

Any idea how I could change that? Here what I've got some far: http://goo.gl/JbXkzC

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your button can't be an isotope item if you don't want it part of the isotope layout so it is incorporated into the layout. You could use isotope's  [stamp option](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#stamp) but the easiest way is to move it out of the col-xs-12 and into the row-fluid and change your button css slightly:

[codepen](http://codepen.io/macsupport/pen/JoExEq)

html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<h1>Isotope Image Grid</h1>
<!--<button class="" id="button">Load More</button>-->
</div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row-fluid">
 <div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </div>     
</div><button id="button">Load More</button>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#button {
  display:inline-block;
 width: 25%;
 height: 180px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 18px;
 background-color: #C0392B;
 border: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Macsupport, unfortunately with the solution you provided the button now doesn't really sit within that fluid grid but underneath it, in what seems to be a new row. 

[Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/5rj143)

Comment: Exactly my point and of course it looks like your screenshot, since it is set up outside the isotope grid! If your button is an isotope item, it will not be static unless you make it a stamp or not have it an isotope item, as previously stated. Here it is as a stamp [codepen](http://codepen.io/macsupport/pen/emgaEP). What you want is difficult without one of these solutions.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying that. I tried to stamp the item, but after reading through a couple of different resources, apparently it is not possible to stamp an item to a bottom corner. Found another solution though, which I will post here in a second.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the only solution to this is to remove the "Load More" button and re-add it once the new elements have been appended.

```
$('#portfolioGrid').on("click", ".loadMore", function(addIsotopeItems){

     addIsotopeItems.preventDefault();

     var OElem = document.getElementById("button");
     OElem.parentNode.removeChild(OElem);

     var di="<div class=\'item item-new\'><img src=\'\'></img></div><button class=\'item loadMore\' id=\'button\'>Load More</button>";

     newItems = $(di).appendTo('#portfolioGrid');
     $("#portfolioGrid").isotope('insert', newItems );
});
```

Full code [here on CodePen](http://codepen.io/maximilianoertel/pen/OPWdJX).